# Storing a reference to a component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The following code:

```js
<View>
  {array.map((obj) => (
    <MyComponent prop1={obj.prop1} prop2={obj.prop2} key={obj.id} />
  ))}
</View>
```

will generate as many `MyComponent` instances as there are elements in an array.

What is the correct way to store a reference to each instance so that the reference can later be used to perform an action on the component?

For example, get the second instance generated, and when an event (outside the component) takes place, change the style associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an element-local variable to store your list of elements:

```js
function ParentComponent(props) {
  // With class-based components you would write
  // this.componentRefs = []
  // in the constructor of the component.
  const componentRefs = useRef([]);

  const externalEventHandler = useCallback((event) => {
    const affectedIndex = calculate({ from: event.something });
    componentRefs.current[affectedIndex].someMethod();
  });

  const componentList = <View>
  {
    props.array.map((obj, index) =>
      <MyComponent ref={ref => componentRefs.current[index] = ref} prop1={obj.prop1} prop2={obj.prop2} key={obj.id} />
    )
  }
  </View>

  return <FancyWrapper onSelect={externalEventHandler}>{componentList}</FancyWrapper>;
}
```

That said, this is not the React way to do things.  "Props down" would suggest that this data flow is better for understanding and composability:

```js
function ParentComponent(props) {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(() => Array(props.array.length).fill(someUsefulDefault));

  const externalEventHandler = useCallback((event) => {
    const affectedIndex = calculate({ from: event.something });
    setSomeState(currentState => {
      const newState = currentState.slice();
      newState[affectedIndex] = calculateNewValue(affectedIndex);
      return newState;
    });
  });

  const componentList = <View>
  {
    array.map((obj, index) =>
      <MyComponent importantProp={someState[index]} prop1={obj.prop1} prop2={obj.prop2} key={obj.id} />
    )
  }
  </View>

  return <FancyWrapper onSelect={externalEventHandler}>{componentList}</FancyWrapper>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try them out. The first, with useRef, looks easy to understand and much more straightforward. The second, have to get my head around. Would like to know why the first is not the 'react way'

Comment: @user1052610: "the core premise for React is that UIs are simply a projection of data into a different form of data". The first example calls a method on the component to make it update while the second example updates the data which in turn updates the UI. The React team has written a bit about this model [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-basic#readme). Hopefully that makes some sense.

Comment: @ Sean Vieira am trying your first solution because the second is not clear to me (do not see importantProp used elsewhere in the example). With solution one, when trying to traverse componentRefs to see what is in it, get: TypeError: componentRefs.forEach is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes